# Obtaining an algorithm

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a variable *a* and *b*. Now I want to find a value for *c* such that the fraction *a* / *c* is a positive integer, and where *c* is as close to *b* as possible.

For example: *a* = 100 and *b* = 30. 
In this case I want *c* to be 25; because *a* / *c* is an integer, and *c* is as close as *b* for which this holds.

Any ideas how I can program a function in C++ which does exactly this?

Comment: Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Has anyone introduced you to the modulo operator, `%`?

Comment: So you are wanting the integer closest to `b` that evenly divides `a`? That should be relatively simple with a few basic modular arithmetic identities. Start with `a % b` and how `a % b` relates to `a % (b + n)`...

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the factors of a. (search web for methods)
2. Scan resulting list for minimum difference vs b.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework assignment? Either way, think about how you would solve this problem without writing any code. A good algorithm comes from a good design. Break the problem down into pieces and walk through some more examples. For example, how would you solve the problem of determining whether the division results in an integer value? Hint: There is a different operator you could use as opposed to division to achieve this easily. Now, how would you solve the problem of determining what number to start at for *c* in the algorithm? Do not write any code until you have the pseudocode figured out.

Comment: It's more like a comment.